# Is it faster to call Spark functions all at once, versus calling them separately?

Tags: performance, function, pyspark

I'm curious if it's faster or more efficient to call Spark (PySpark) functions all at once versus calling them separately?

For example:

```
final_df = data_frame1.doFirstThing() \
                      .doSecondThing() \
                      .doThirdThing() \
                      .doFourthThing()
```

versus

```
data_frame2 = data_frame1.doFirstThing()
data_frame3 = data_frame2.doSecondThing()
data_frame4 = data_frame3.doThirdThing()
final_df = data_frame4.doFourthThing()
```

I tend to see a lot of the first method, but it makes debugging harder.  Was curious about how this is handled and whether or not I'm shooting myself in the foot by breaking things out into separate manipulations.

Comment: Most likely doesn't make a difference - you can check the execution plans to see that both do the same thing under the hood: `final_df.explain()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is it doesn't matter, spark is lazy and won't do the First, Second, Third, ... things until you call an action, ie `.write` or `.collect` or similar. Until then it just records what you've asked it to do.

That being said, it also depends on how you're debugging. When you say "it makes debugging harder", if you mean that you want to inspect the schema and column names between operations, that's fine. However if you're calling `data_frame.take` or `data_frame.show` between steps, you might really be shooting yourself in the foot. Spark can sometimes be very smart, for example if you do `df.select(df.col_a - df.col_b).where(df.col_a > df.col_b)`, spark will invert the order of those operations because there's no point in doing a computation you're just going to throw away. If you materialize a partial result, spark may not be able to optimize as much as it could if it had the full query, also spark doesn't always cache intermediate results so those computations may need to be repeated when you run your final query.

TLDR, breaking things up is fine, be mindful about the actions you run on intermediate dataframes.

Comment: Right.  I do run individual examinations (e.g. df.show()) between steps in debug mode, then turn that off for production.  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't inadvertently causing myself headaches.  Thanks!